# System integration for Document Management

Tags: file-management, document-management

In my Class there are serveral groups with different Projects. One of the Project which my group has gotten, is to gather and orginze all the Information/Docuemnts from the other groups for Evaluation purposes.

Every groupe uses these 4 tools.

1. Jira for tracking and organize all the issues/Tasks.
2. GitHub for Developing
3. Has an Folder on a Lokal Server where they need to Save all relevant Dokuments.
4. A Platform where every group member needs to Protocol everything they have done for this Project.

Jira and GitHub provide API`s which we can use to get information about the groups and the Project itself. (Statistics and Commit history etc..) We also have full access to the Database where all the Protocols and Dokumentation are saved.

There are almos no restriction in how we solve this issue. The only handicap is that it needs to run on an internal server.

Right now we are gathering ideas of how we can solve this. We have taken a look at Slack (which is no option anymore), WebDAV and some other stuff.

Are there any good Frameworks/Platforms etc.. which support somthing like this or do we need to to Program everything from ground up our self?

If anything is unclear, please ask!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You just wrote "gather and organize", which is very vague. Please describe precisely what the software should do. Also, what is the "local server"? Is it an Alfresco server? And what is the name of the 4th tool?

Comment: The goal of this Project is to simplify the evaluation of the other Groups. Right now everything from GitHub, Jira, Other Dokuments and the Protocols need to be gatheret separately. 
We want a "Dashboard" where the information of those 4 sources (GitHub, Jira, Database with Dokuments and Databse with Protocols) are easly accessible and nicely Orginized. Also it should be Possible to Create notes for the information we have gathered. 
Jira, Database with Dokuments and Protocols run on a NAS server. 
Everything should be Automated (like a Continuous integration environment).

Comment: What do you call "Protocols"? Is it a kind of document? And for documents, what document information do you want to show on the dashboard? Who modified what recently? Who read what recently? Show how many documents there are now?

Comment: Yes the Protocols are just another set of Documents. Dont know which format right now. 
We only need the Document it self. It will be Evaluated what the Group wrote etc..
Its like gathering everything a Groupe has done over a certain time and Evaluate it (make comments). And that somehow easy and Automated.

Comment: So, just an HTTP link to the document(s) is enough? All documents/protocols are accessible over WebDAV?

Comment: Yeah i think so. WebDAV was one of the suggestion. But we have never used this Protocol bevore

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Liferay](https://www.liferay.com).
Liferay is a portal server, which means its goal is to integrate information from other systems.

In Liferay, you organize a page (which you could call a "dashboard") by drag-and-dropping "portlets" on it. In the screenshot below, the portlets palette is on the left, and the result page is the center+right:

[image: Liferay]

There are [thousands of portlets](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace) for pretty much anything you might need.

- For instance, here is a [JIRA metrics portlet](https://github.com/liferay-labs/jira-metrics-portlet), it shows how many bugs got created/solved/etc.
- For Github I recommend using the [generic IFrame portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Iframe+Portlet) and configuring it with the Github project's URL.
- For WedDAV (Documents/"Protocols") I recommend using the generic IFrame portlet and configuring it with the WebDAV server's URL/username/password.

Liferay is free, open source, and easy to install on any server.

Here is how a typical Liferay portal looks like after you have drag-and-dropped and configured all of the components you want:

[image: Liferay portal]
[image: Liferay Documents and Media]

Comment: Thanks! Liferay looks promesing. 
Do you have any experience with this portal server? 
Is it easy to develop cusomt Portlets?

Comment: Yes, I have experience running Liferay, configuring it and developing custom portlets. It is extremely easy for IFrame portlets (no actual development needed). For more complex needs, it is still convenient thanks to [Liferay IDE](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-ide/overview).

Comment: Hey, Nicolas!
We are considering to use Liferay for our Project but have some more questions, maybe you could share your thoughts with us.
The goal for us is it to setup Liferay, so the Professors have a Login and immediately see the necessary informtion from the portlets. Also it should be possible to search for an group/user and after the search, all the portlets should update. Is this possible?
Do you have any idea how we could add a note function? They want to add notes to happenings from the different sources.
What about access all the services from an mobile devices?
A Big Thanks!!

Comment: Notes: Many notes portlets can be found at http://www.liferay.com/marketplace ... could you please post a new question asking for such a Liferay portlet and specifying exactly what kind of sources you want to be compatible?

Comment: Mobile: Yes, Liferay scales down nicely on mobile. Responsive design.

Comment: Info about a particular user group: Yes this is doable, actually it is one of the examples found in the Liferay manual (I don't remember exactly which one). Please ask about this on the Liferay forum, thanks!

Comment: Hey Nicolas,
(last questions)
are there any Alternatives to Liferay which i can compare it to? 
I found Alfresco, but i have the feeling that it is not customizable like Liferay. I did not find any way to build Cusomt extansions (plugins/addons) like the Portlets in Liferay. 
Im asking because i have to check for alternatives in my research for my solution.

Comment: Alfresco is not a portal, it is an Enterprise Content Management system, which means you could use it to manage documents, but its usual role is not to show information from heterogeneous systems. Real portal alternatives to Liferay: JBoss Portal, Jetspeed. See http://www.fulcrumlogic.com/knowledgeCenter/WhitePapers/Comparitive%20Evaluation%20of%20Portals%20-%20Liferay,%20JBoss,%20Apache%20Jetspeed.pdf